# How to create an Azure Virtual Machine on a second subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

When I create a new Virtual Machine in Azure, I cannot select my second subscription. They are both visible on my account, except on the drop-down list when creating Virtual Machines.

I have two subscriptions in my Windows Azure account. The first one is a 3-month trial. Then I opened a Bizspark account. Since the Virtual Machine feature is in preview, the technical support closed my ticket and asked me to refer to forums, which I couldn't find anywhere on the Azure account page.

Comment: did you enable the preview feature on the second account?

Comment: Good question. I did not know the preview works on a subscription basis and not on an account basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. Went to this page:

https://account.windowsazure.com/PreviewFeatures

and clicked on "sign up again" to Virtual Machines.